# Правильная привязка для UserControl

Tags: wpf, binding, usercontrol

подскажите, пожалуйста один момент в привязке данных.

Есть UserControl с DependencyProperty Item, которая должна принимать объекта класса Home.

Есть ListView c ItemsSourse, являющимся List. Как правильно указать привязку на каждый элемент списка для свойства Item каждого UserControl?

Заранее спасибо

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <usercontrols:ElementGraphVisual  Item="{Binding .}" ></usercontrols:ElementGraphVisual>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Приведенный код не работает? В нем я проблем не вижу

Comment: Перепроверил работает, но моя проблема в том, что мне нужно что в коде би хайнд юзерконтроля при изменении искомого свойства привяязки можно было реализовать определенный механизм обновления содержимого, как этого добиться ?

Comment: Покажите как вы создаете DP в контроле